# Docker desktop having problems running with wsl

Tags: linux, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I have installed docker desktop v4.27.2(and 4.27.1) and neither of them worked and as I opened the desktop app, it gave me this error:

> Wsl.exe --update --web-download not supported

(I have reinstalled wsl and docker desktop multiple times, I have checked the wsl chekbox in windows features, and I have installed ubuntu using both `wsl --install`, and the wsl.exe app)

it seems like docker cannot connect to wsl, but I don't know how to fix it.

and whenever I start the docker desktop app, it gives me the error and closes the program.
this is the docker and wsl versions:

> docker -v: Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
> wsl -l -v: Ubuntu 2